# send urlrequest with same session id as webview

Tags: swift

i have a `WKWebView` where users can login onto my server.
i also have a site that can be called from the background to renew the session time.
However, that request needs the same session cookie as my webview.
Since the cookies are handled by `HTTPCookieStorage`, my first attempt was to just send the request with

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: DOMAIN + PAGE_KEEP_ALIVE)!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
task.resume()
```

But that didn't work(i can see the invalid time of all current sessions on my server).
So, i tried adding the cookies to the request:

```
let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies(for: URL(string: DOMAIN)!)
let headers = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies!)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: DOMAIN + PAGE_KEEP_ALIVE)!)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
task.resume()
```

but it still didn't work. Finally i tried `request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true`, but it still didn't help and i'm now out of ideas. Can anyone help me?

edit: after the comment from Larme the following worked

```
    let store = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore
    store.getAllCookies { cookies in
        let domainCookies = cookies.filter { c in c.domain == DOMAIN }
        let headers=HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: domainCookies)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: DOMAIN + PAGE_KEEP_ALIVE)!)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields=headers
        let task = URLSession.shared.webSocketTask(with: request)
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: According to the doc: "Each WKWebView instance has its own cookie storage." (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/httpcookiestorage ). So are you retrieving the correct one? Also what's the value of `headers` in your second attempt?

Comment: @Larme see edit